# Saving console log in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-3.5

I'm working on quite big project(a lot of modules) and I want to save whole stdout to a file. I tried logging library, but it saves only output of log(something). In project there is a lot of print(). So how can I save whole content of console (basically stdout) to a file? Important is that stdout must be still visible.

Comment: `open(pythonfile, 'r').read().replace('print(', 'logging.logger.info(')`

Comment: In linux: `python yourfilename.py > outputfilelog`

Comment: In some other module there is runned logging library. If I try to save stdout in any way, record is interrupted just after calling to logging